# Is it possible to bake the volumetric output of a modelled light from its geometry?

Tags: lighting

I am trying to generate a functionally realistic automotive headlight however while they are sealed and self-contained, they are almost disgustingly complex internally with many reflective surfaces. This creates perhaps the worst kind of headache for noise and fireflies while trying to illuminate a very rough road surface.

I feel like the only option is to simulate once, the headlight in isolation, and develop a volumetric emission map of light, and then insert that light source into the model. The headlight would then only need to be simulated for direct appearance to the camera, and its indirect light coming from a predetermined light.

I have no idea if or how this might even be possible, or what keywords or features I might be looking for. Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

So, I recently helped someone out with the task of making proper headlights. What we did in the end was the following:
We put in a little point lamp inside the headlights. Not so much, that they have a big influence on the outside of the headlight, but enough to make the headlight glow in a convincing manner.
Then, just before the headlamp we placed spotlights with some good brightness and enough of a light size/radius (not talking about the 1 to 45 degree of light cone angle).
Now that we had the spotlights with their fine little lines, so you can see where the light will end up being we put in cylinders, deleted the top and bottom faces, made them match the spotlight ray in size and gave it principled volume.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Edit: 
About the fireflies: Do not forget that you are in posession of a fine tool named "Denoiser"
Put the noise threshold fro 0.1 to 0.01 and render out 50 samples+denoise. Not happy? 100 samples+ denoise. Still not happy? 150+ denoise etc. Saves a whole lot of time and headache and with a good ratio between denoise and samples you save yourself the photo realism as good as you can.

Comment: I'll be honest I have tried my hand with the denoiser. For the most part I'm just getting some kind of Jackson Pollock of crazy colour wherever my light projects...

Comment: The 'light can' seems like a really interesting option..! Does an emissive surface behave like a light source directly?